# Is there any way I can automate configuring Nexus 3?

Tags: docker, ansible, nexus

I am currently setting up a nexus3 OSS server. I've created and ansible role that wil set up an official nexus3 docker container behing and nginx reverse proxy. I have my storage setup separately so my artifacts will persist if the instance gets killed (for say, a base image update). I'd like to set up the ansible role so I don't have to go into the nexus gui to setup LDAP and repositories everytime I recreate the server. Is there a way to inject this kind of configuration into nexus?

Comment: did you check this https://opennxos.cisco.com/public/codeshop/ansible-module-for-nexus-switches/

Comment: Technically this would not be automation, but you could simply put the `${nexus_home}/etc` [directory](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#directories) in your persistent datastore. In the [Nexus Repository](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/nexus-3.0.x/scripting/complex-script/security.groovy) are some examples, you might be able to script the setup as well.

Comment: Have a look here: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html

Comment: @HenrikPingel this is what I ended up doing, I've just mounted an EBS that holds the nexus data dirs. It's not very pretty but it works, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've just resorted to creating proxy-repositories in nexus2, I'll turn these into hosted repo's later. The storage here is much more straightforward and accessible and I've hosted it on a discrete persistent EBS. I'll use this for now and upgrade to 3.1 when that's released. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Nexus Repository Manager 3 includes a scripting API that you can use for this sort of work. Have a look at the [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html) and the [demo videos](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/06/08/integrating-nexus-repository-3/).

If you find anything we should expand the API on or need some help [contact us on the mailing list or via live chat.](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/lists-live-chat-and-other-resources/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty easy workaround to automate nexus, I usually do that by following the nexus API which uses an API documentation tool called swagger, in order to do that you can go to http://localhost:8081/#admin/system/api or you can go to:

```
System administration and configuration > System > API
```

you can check the complete API documentation of nexus and so to do the provisioning you can create a script containing multiple curl calling any API you want.
the generated API request will look like this:

```bash
    # Add jenkins user
    curl -X 'POST' \
        "http://${NEXUS_URL}/service/rest/v1/security/users" \
        -u "admin:admin123" \
        -H 'accept: application/json' \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -d '{
  "userId" : "jenkins",
  "firstName" : "jenkins",
  "lastName" : "jenkins",
  "emailAddress" : "jenkins@domain.com",
  "password" : "jenkins",
  "status" : "active",
  "roles" : [ "nx-admin" ]
}'
```

> this for example will create a new jenkins user.
>
> > You can find more in [nexus API documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api)